# Head node of a linked list

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I don't quite get the concept of head node in a linked list. In a LinkedList class below, head is null in the default constructor. Should it always stay as null, or do we need to assign it a value when we use this class in another program?

```
public class LinkedList implements ListInterface {
  private Node head; 
  private int numItems; 

  public LinkedList() {
  numItems = 0;
  head = null;
  }
```

Say I want to create a new LinkedList called ListOne, and make it a circular linked list. Do I assign a value to head like head= listOne.find (0); ? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The head is an encapsulated member of the list. Since you are asking to make a list by name, I'm assuming that you are using the list in your application. You shouldn't have to reference the head, just the list itself.

his shows you how to use LinkedList in java: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_linkedlist_class.htm